# VS 2013 WPF UserControl C# Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

While working through a UserControl example I had trouble getting the code to work.  Admittedly I had a few typos along the way but even after they were all cleared up, I still had an error from the xaml parser saying that the class failed to construct.

The error occurred in the xaml of the main window of the test app...

```
<Window x:Class="CH10.TestUserControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:CH10.UserControls;assembly=CH10.UserControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--The error occurred in the following line-->
        <ctrls:ColorPicker SelectedColor="AntiqueWhite" 
                           SelectedColorChanged="OnColorChanged"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="_tbcolor" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Margin="8" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

I managed to trick it into throwing the exact same error by causing a runtime error in the registration of a DP...

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '10'.
  HResult=-2146233087
  IsTransient=false
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '10'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=13
  LinePosition=10
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       _HResult=-2146233036
       _message=The type initializer for 'CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker' threw an exception.
       HResult=-2146233036
       IsTransient=false
       Message=The type initializer for 'CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker' threw an exception.
       Source=CH10.UserControls
       TypeName=CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker
       StackTrace:
            at CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker..ctor()
       InnerException: System.ArgumentException
            _HResult=-2147024809
            _message=Default value type does not match type of property 'SelectedColor'.
            HResult=-2147024809
            IsTransient=false
            Message=Default value type does not match type of property 'SelectedColor'.
            Source=WindowsBase
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.ValidateDefaultValueCommon(Object defaultValue, Type propertyType, String propertyName, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback, Boolean checkThreadAffinity)
                 at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterCommon(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata defaultMetadata, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)
                 at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)
                 at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata)
                 at CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker..cctor() in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CH10.UserControls\CH10.UserControls\ColorPicker.xaml.cs:line 26
            InnerException:
```

The above error is the same one that threw but artificially created by me.  The only difference was that the stacktrace on the original error took me to the first line of this method...

```
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<Color> SelectedColorChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(SelectedColorChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedColorChangedEvent, value); }
    }
```

I pasted the same code from the working version over this and it didn't make any difference.

---

I started comparing the code I had entered with the downloaded version for the book I'm working through and the only difference I could find was in the Settings.Designer.cs file in the UserControl folder.  This line in particular...

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
```

The context is...

```
namespace CH10.UserControls.Properties
{


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
    {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default
        {
            get
            {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the downloaded version of the code it had "10.0.0.0" instead of "11.0.0.0"...

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
```

So, even though its auto-generated (I guess when the project is set up), I changed my version to match and suddenly everything worked.

Then I changed it back and it still worked.

What does this directive do, when is the code generated and why would it cause such problems?

the code is in this [github repo](https://github.com/cool-Blue/CH10.UserControls)

There are two components, the UserControl and an application to test it.
The Settings.Designer.cs file in the test app has "11.0.0.0" and I haven't changed it.

After faking the rror, I started getting false errors like this...

> Exception: The component 'CH10.UserControls.ColorPicker' does not have
>   a resource identified by the URI
>   '/CH10.UserControls;component/colorpicker.xaml'.

But shutdown/restart gets rid of it.

Comment: @gmetax sorry mate, I must have been doing the exact same edit as you at the exact same time!

Comment: So what was the original error message?

Comment: @DirkVollmar, good question, It didn't help me to understand so I didn't record and now I can't repro it, but the gist of it was as explained in the post. I'll update it to show the exact line of xaml where it threw...

Comment: It seems unlikely that the change in the attribute is related to your problem. Probably you did other changes as well, which makes it now difficult to tell what the problem was. The code in your repo just compiles fine.

Comment: @DirkVollmar, mate, I swear... I only changed that one number and then rebuilt it. I also noticed other signs of instability such as squiggly line warnings about unresolved references that would disappear after I closed and reopened the solution. Is this a common thing or did I just get un-lucky?

Comment: What you saw as an error in the editor then most likely was related to the fact that you hadn't compiled your project at least once. The XAML editor is a little picky as it requires your user control to be already compiled. Simply pressing F5 and running your project would have worked without giving you and compiler errors, I guess.

Comment: @DirkVollmar, yep, I'm aware of that: I was careful to "rebuild" the usercontrol and then "rebuild the solution before hitting F5.